# CATIA VBA preserving constraints when moving around parts

Tags: vba, catia

I have a macro for CATIA V5 that I wrote in VBA, where I move around parts in the specification tree.

But when I do that the constraints between the parts get lost.
I want to keep those constraints.

However when I look for the references in through the constraint object I only get the name of the BREP, without any information as to which part that BREP actually belongs to.

Any tips on what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep the constrains because reordering in specification tree with vba is done by cut-paste operation. I don't know with CAA...but I suppose you don't have that expensive  license.

If you use only Fix constraints, then best idea it would be to delete them and fix again.

Comment: Actually it is possible, put a little complicated. Basically I have to extract the name of the reference before the copy-paste and the name of the constraint. Then I have to create a new reference with the name and assign it to the constraint. I did it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

it is part of the copy paste properties.
If you go to Tools => Options => Assembly design => Constraints, you can find a way to copy paste data with the constraints.

There should be a way to activate those parameters in your macro.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicholas stated, You need to change the setting in Tools --> Options --> Mechanical Design --> Assembly Design --> Constraints --> Paste components --> [select "Always with assembly constraints"]

An automated way to ask the user if they want this setting changed is as follows:

```
Dim settingControllers1 As SettingControllers
Set settingControllers1 = CATIA.SettingControllers
Dim asmConstraintSettingAtt1 As AsmConstraintSettingAtt
Set asmConstraintSettingAtt1 = settingControllers1.Item("CATAsmConstraintSettingCtrl")
If asmConstraintSettingAtt1.PasteComponentMode = catPasteWithoutCsts Or asmConstraintSettingAtt1.PasteComponentMode = catPasteWithCstOnCut Then
    Dim iResponseForSetting As Integer
    iResponseForSetting = MsgBox("Setting for retaining constaints during Copy is not active" & vbNewLine & "Do you want to change this setting?", vbYesNo)
    If iResponseForSetting = vbYes Then
        asmConstraintSettingAtt1.PasteComponentMode = catPasteWithCstOnCopyAndCut
    End If
End If
```